# Specflow beforeScenario in base class called multiple times, once for each feature in the suite

Tags: c#, specflow, allure

I have a test suite that utilizes a test reporting framework that I need to run through a base class, everything works fine but the [BeforeScenario] is being called 10 times for every scenario I run, 1 time for each feature in my suite, strangely the teardown only runs once.

Here is what my base class looks like:

```
[Binding]
public class BaseStep : AllureReport
{
    public DriverSupport _support;
    public BaseStep(DriverSupport support)
    {
        _support = support;
    }

    [BeforeScenario]
    public void Setup(FeatureContext context)
    {
            _support.startDriver();
            AllureLifecycle.Instance.RunStep(() =>
            {
                TestContext.Progress.WriteLine(
                    $"Test \"{TestExecutionContext.CurrentContext.CurrentTest.FullName}\" is starting...");
            });

    }

    [AfterScenario, Order(0)]
    private void TearDown()
    {

        AllureLifecycle.Instance.RunStep(() =>
        {
            TestContext.Progress.WriteLine(
                $"Test {TestExecutionContext.CurrentContext.CurrentTest.FullName}\" is stopping...");
        });

}
```

And this is what my feature step file looks like (there are 10 of these)

```
[Binding]
public class TestSteps1:BaseStep
{

    public TestSteps1(DriverSupport support) : base(suppprt)
    {
    }

    [Given(@"user goes to (.*)")]
    public void GivenUserGoesTo(string p0)
    {
        _support.driver.GoToUrl(p0)
    }
```

When I run just ONE scenario in a feature by themselves, it will print start the driver and print "test xxx is starting..." 10 times, once for each feature I have, I just want it to run once.

I have thought of moving beforescenario to the step classes themselves, but many of my features use steps from multiple step files, so I think that would be an issue. Is there any way to make it so it only runs BeforeScenario one time per scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SpecFlow will execute the BeforeScenario method for each type it finds in your test project. It looks like there are 10 types that define or inherit this method:

- The BaseStep class
- Each sub class of BaseStep

When I want a BeforeScenario to run only once per test run I will put it into its own "hooks" class.

Since both the before and after hooks should only execute once, just put both of them in something like `SpecFlowHooks.cs`.

The Selenium web driver object should be registered with the SpecFlow dependency injection framework, and passed directly to each step class as a constructor argument. Given the code you posted, I'm not sure a common base class for your step definitions is beneficial.

See my answer for [How to properly manage and access webdriver instances to avoid problems with parallel execution of tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58394163/3092298) for more information about properly registering a Selenium web driver object with SpecFlow.

Comment: I removed my base class and moved its methods to a hooks class as you suggested, I used my DriverSuport class instead of a IWebdriver for the container, and everything including reporting works just the way it should now, Thank you!